# Mix Lombok, Java and Scala in a maven project

Tags: java, scala, maven, compilation, lombok

I've got a mixed Scala/Java maven project where the application code, unit and integration tests are written in Java but performance tests are written in Scala.

The Scala performance tests depend on a couple Java Integration Test classes that have `@Data` Lombok annotations. In order for getters and setters to work I must compile `JavaThenScala`, which I can do through IntelliJ Scala Compiler settings.

My question is - Is there a way I can set my maven plugins to do the `JavaThenScala` compilation without adjusting the IntelliJ settings since I would like to deploy the code elsewhere?

I am trying to use the `compileOrder` configuration but it doesn't seem to do the trick for me.

My maven plugins:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>met.alchim31.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <compileOrder>JavaThenScala</compileOrder>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
        <artifactId>gatling-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: what happen when you run `mvn clean package`?

Comment: hey @JRichardsz, I see `Error: value getVariable is not a member of the Class` where it is located under @Data annotation. If I change @Data to an actual getter ,it works or if I change Scala compiler setting on IntelliJ to JavaThenScala and re-compile it works as well

Comment: I'm not sure scala-maven-plugin works properly with Java annotation processing.

Comment: Where does your error occur? In your scala test, right? It would be helpful if you share a mvp of your project. A simple spring bean with its test.

Comment: It is some strange. mvn package first compile all the java class , then the tests and after that runs the test

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disclaimer: Gatling founder and scala-maven-plugin co-maintainer here

Annotation processing, in particular Lombok, is a super weird beast.
It seems scala-maven-plugin doesn't support it, see https://github.com/davidB/scala-maven-plugin/issues/342 (was closed due to lack of activity/contribution).

Then, I recommend you isolate your Gatling tests in a dedicated module, so you can build your Lombok based test classes in a pure Java module that would publish a [test jar](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html) and then have your Gatling module depend on this test-jar.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it! I feel like at this point I might just add an actual getter instead of lombok @Data annotation for the few variables I need for Scala and roll with that. Not the prettiest option but it will work.

Comment: For your information, Gatling 3.7 will bring a Java DSL too.

Comment: Agree, just not using Lombok in the few places you need might be the easiest solution.

Comment: Ended up just creating a method `getScalaValues()` in my `TestUtils.java` class that gets all values I need using lombok and puts them in a hashmap. Then just created a `val scalaValues: util.Map[String, String] = TestUtils.getScalaValues` in Scala and used it to populate the fields. That was the cleanest solution I could come up with since I am not that worried about it being a bit slower.